# Using polymorphism to move objects of different subclasses

Tags: java, polymorphism, mouseevent, abstract-class, jcomponent

I am trying to repaint a chess piece after I have moved it with my mouse. The move() method should take in the instance field variables after they have been obtained from the MouseEvents and move the Piece object from it's original (source) location to it's destination . Note the Piece class is abstract and contains 7 different subclasses. However the mouseevents have been implemented and printing out the correct rows and coloumns and the dummy pieces are also being printed but the objects in the new locations are not being printed. Any suggestions on why?

```
public class Chess extends JComponent implements MouseListener {



     public static final int ROW = 8, COLUMN = 8; 

     private Piece[][] chessPieces=new Piece[ROWS][COLS];



     private int sourceR,destR,sourceC,destC;




 public void  move () {

     chessPieces[destR][destC]=chessPieces[sourceR][sourceC]; 
   //This is not taking the Piece object and moving it to the new place?!



      System.out.print("destR is "+destR+"destC IS "+destC+"sourceR is"
      +sourceR+ "sourceC is "+sourceC+"\n"); 

      chessPieces[sourceR][sourceC]= new Dummy();//removes original piece leaves blank aka dummy 


       repaint();
 }

 public void paintComponent (Graphics h) { 

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)h;
    for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {

      for(int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) {

        theBoard[row][col].paint(g); 
        chessPieces[row][col].paint(g); 
      }
    }


 }


  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {

      sourceR=event.getX()/45; // 
      sourceC=event.getY()/45; //here we get the location of the piece to be MOVED


  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {

     destR=event.getX()/45; //PLACE IT'S MOVED TO
      destC=event.getY()/45; //PLACE IT'S MOVED TO

     move();
  }

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}

 }
```

Comment: Provide [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: First thing you should do is call super.paintComponent at the start of your overridden paintComponent. Something else I notice is if `theBoard` and `chessPieces` are arrays of extended JComponents you shouldn't be calling paint directly on them. Call `repaint()`. You may not need to override paintComponent in Chess at all because the JComponent paint method will paint the children. Hard to tell exactly what's going on with what you've provided, sorry.